# code=H10 desc="App crashed" can't find solution why it happened

Tags: node.js, heroku

So I deployed my third app to heroku but to my surprise the app is not working, it's the first time when I get this kind of error:

`code=H10 desc="App crashed"`

At first I forgot to set my port variable like this: `const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;`

And then listen to it like this:

```
server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server is runing on port 5000');
});
```

But even when I set up `port` variable I still get the same error and I don't know what can cause this error.

```
2018-10-04T15:12:29.405064+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=m-o-d.herokuapp.com request_id=430f142b-4820-410b-865b-cc6bffae2fa5 fwd="195.12.167.97" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-04T15:12:29.654458+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=m-o-d.herokuapp.com request_id=30ff6c29-f7c3-4350-aaff-4bc22f823dd8 fwd="195.12.167.97" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

App works when I run it in my localhost like this: `npm start`

```
2018-10-04T17:09:24.933184+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the mystery_of_dungeons@1.0.0 start script.
2018-10-04T17:09:24.921760+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:542:15)
2018-10-04T17:09:24.921763+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
2018-10-04T17:09:24.921766+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please run `heroku logs`, then [edit] your question and add more context to the error message you're showing us. There should be some detailed output from Node.js and / or your own code.

Comment: How to run `heroku logs` ?? @Chris

Comment: The `H10` errors you've shared are coming from your logs. If you're logging to `stdout` you should see a stack trace associated with these `H10` errors.

Comment: @BradleyJohnson I've updated my post with more errors. Does these help?